# Phaser calculate needed y velocity for given y point

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

In my mobile game, the main character needs to jump to a specific y point before starting to fall down again due to gravity. How could I calculate the y velocity I would need to reach (at peak) a given y position with a given gravity?

I tried to do this with a tween instead of arcade physics because it was exactly what I needed (distance traveled over time with a gravity-like effect), but the performance was not good and was constantly sputtering.

I'm currently using Phaser 2.6.2. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 kinds of time in games, cycle based time and deltaTime.

**In a cycle based scenario, the physics don't shift to account for lag so the best solution is this:**

You start off with number sequence where you compound gravity with the previous number in the sequence until your sum total equals your desired height.

For an example, I will use height = 75, gravity = 5, and jumpForce=unknown

(5+10+15+20+25)=75

The jump force you need to reach this height will be the last number in the sequence which is "25".

**In a deltaTime Scenario (as used in this case), the physics are abstracted to try to adjust to time.**

So, if you have 5fps, you'll have 5 cycles/second.  if you have 20 fps, you'll have 20 cycles per second; so, this abstraction makes the above irrelevant.

Instead use the standard gravity formula of height = velocity^2 / (2 * gravity)., because this will better model to the formulas used by delta time engines.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm not understanding your logic or it just doesn't work for my situation. The gravity I'm using is 1400 but the distance I need to travel is 440

Comment: Try height = velocity^2 / (2 * gravity).  So: JumpVelocity = 1110.

Comment: That second one is incredibly close! It's just a tiny bit off as I double and triple the gravity  (it was about 8 pixels short when I doubled the gravity), but I think it's something I can make a minor adjustment to as I increase the speed of everything! Please edit your answer and I'll mark it as the correct one :)

Comment: That margin of error is from rounding.  Delta time is often considered to be better for game development because it keeps lag from slowing down your gaming experience, but it also comes with a number of draw backs when it comes to precisely modeling physics.  To consider this in your level designs, record your jump height under no lag, then try to lag your computer with other stuff to create a high lag case scenario.  If this causes different jump heights, then make sure that all "passable" areas can be reached with the lower jump height, and all impassable areas can block the greater one.